# react and react table: Problem with Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm getting this error when rendering a react-table in React typescript

> caught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

That is the code related to this:

```
import {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from "react";
import ManagementService from "../services/ManagementService";
import MasterSet from "../model/MasterSet";
import {Column, useTable} from "react-table";

const ShowMastersets: React.FC = () => {

const [mastersets, setMastersets] = useState<Array<MasterSet>>([]);
const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    retrieveMastersets();
}, []);

const columns: Array<Column<MasterSet>> = [
    {
        Header: "Masterset ID",
        accessor: "mastersetId"
    },
    {
        Header: "Masterset Name",
        accessor: "mastersetName"
    },
    {
        Header: "Key Name",
        accessor: "keyName"
    },
    {
        Header: "Key Start Time",
        accessor: "keyStartTime"
    }
    ];

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
} = useTable({
    columns,
    data: mastersets
});

return (
    <div className="list row">
        <div className="col-md-12 list">
            <table
                className="table table-striped table-bordered"
                {...getTableProps()}
            >
                <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup: any) => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((column: any) => (
                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                {column.render("Header")}
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row, i) => {
                    prepareRow(row);
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return (
                                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                                );
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default ShowMastersets;
```

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong? I have removed the parts of the controller which are not needed.

Comment: Hard to tell what is wrong, can you debug by commenting to find out what line actually causing the problem? I think the problem come from `useTable` or one of its callback

Comment: I tried to debug, but I am not sure how to find the proper way. I used Web Developer Tools and could see, that useTable is called lots of times even when the table is completly displayed. I can't see why this happens

Answer (score 0):

I would offer 2 suggestions to deal with this error: 1) create a type for your data, e.g.

```
export type MasterSet = {
    mastersetId: string;
    ...
}
```

Then you can memoize it as follows:

```
const columns: Column<MasterSet>[] = useMemo(() => [
    ...
],[masterSet]);
```

2. turn autoResetPage to false in your useTable instance, like this:

   ...
   const tableInstance: TableInstance = useTable(
   { columns, data, useSortBy, useExpanded,
   initialState: { pageSize: 10, }, autoResetPage: false },
   ...allHooks
   );
   ...

The latter especially should sort out the problem.